# Laravel upgrade form 5.5 to 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations, laravel-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade laravel application from 5.5 to 5.6
in the documentation, regarding database modification, in Index Order Of Morph Columns section, it was mentioned that

```
If the application is in production, you should pass an explicit index name to the morphs method.
```

What kind of modification should I do there?

Thanks!

Comment: *you may receive an error when attempting to run the migration's down method* so in your migration `down` method when dropping the morph index you need to explicitly pass the index name.

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately, I didn't get it @apokryfos, I didn't get what should I do in the down method, Could you provide a sample?